# Toggling ul inside an li only animates when closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, toggle

I'm trying to open a checkbox of ingredients and it does that just without the animation.

as mentioned on the subject here follows my code:

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="recipePicContainer">
        <div id="checkBoxes">
                <li class="recipe"></li>
                       <ul>
                           <ul><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</ul>
                           <ul><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</ul>
                           <ul><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</ul>
                           <ul><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</ul>
                           <ul>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</ul>
                       </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript

```
 var main = function() {
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('ul').hide();
         $('.recipe').click(function () {
             $('ul').toggle("slow");
         });
    }); }; $(document).ready(main);
```

Thanx guys!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle where the problem can be reproduced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the ingredients need to be separate ul elements? Changing those to li elements fixed the issue.

I also recommend using classes on your elements and selecting based on those classes, rather than selecting and toggling all ul elements on the page.

```js
var main = function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul').hide();
    $('.recipe').click(function() {
      $('ul').toggle("slow");
    });
  });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="recipePicContainer">
    <div id="checkBoxes">
      <li class="recipe">Click</li>
      <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, I didn't really want the * of the li before the listed ingredients, but it's still better than how it worked before.

Comment: Add a class to the `<ul>` element with the css property `list-style: none;`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? Fading it in with [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/). Also added an ID to the `ul` containing all the checkboxes.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#ingredients').hide();
     $('.recipe').click(function () {
         $('#ingredients').fadeIn();
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="recipePicContainer">
    <div id="checkBoxes">
        <li class="recipe">Click me</li>
           <ul id="ingredients">
             <ul><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</ul>
             <ul><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</ul>
             <ul><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</ul>
             <ul><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</ul>
             <ul>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</ul>
         </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

https://jsfiddle.net/sandmehta2014/ccy7s0pe/

I just changed following:

```
<li class="recipe"> 
                       <ul>
                           <li><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
                           <li><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
                           <li><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
                           <li><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
                           <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
                       </ul>
                      </li>
```

> I guess you have taken ul in place of li.

Comment: this wroks better, but it also duplicates an image I have set in the ul several times which isn't needed.